# UITesting Xcode - select specific element?

Tags: xcode, macos, uitest

I am trying to select a specific element (an image) in a scrollview. 
Now if I use UITest recording this is the code it creates for me:

```
[[phocusByHasselbladWindow.scrollBars childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeValueIndicator].element click];
    [[[[phocusByHasselbladWindow childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeSplitGroup].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeSplitGroup].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeScrollView].element click];
```

Now because the list may change I want to select the specific image by name, but I can't figure out how.

This is one of my tries (just below), however it just comes up and says it can't find any element by that name.

```
[[phocusByHasselbladWindow.scrollbars childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeValueIndicator].element click];
    [[[[[phocusByHasselbladWindow childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeSplitGroup].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeSplitGroup].element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeScrollView] elementMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField identifier:@"TestImage"] click];
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use accessibilityIdentifier or accessibiltyLabel and get after you can have access to it.

```
label.accessibiltyLabel = "label"
XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts["label"].exists) // true
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this work? I tried
`XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[@"TestImage"].exists);`
which came out false

Comment: Of course, your image is not a "static text". static text is for UILabel. Try app.images["TestImage"]